# Test an ERB Template

Tags: ruby, json, erb

I've written a template that does some stuff to a JSON object, as an example:

```
{
  "list": [
    <% ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].each do |letter| %>
     <%= puts "{ \"letter\": \"" + letter + "\" }," %>
    <% end %>
   ]
}
```

How can I write a unit test to check if the JSON output is valid? I'm new to Ruby so I don't really know the tools I would use for this. Also, is there a better way to make a list of JSON objects in an ERB template?

I don't have access to, or knowledge of the thing that's processing the template so I'm not really positive about which Ruby libraries I can consume.

**NOTE:** RAILS is not involved. Just vanilla Ruby.

Comment: Have you considered using [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/README.md) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to return some object or list as JSON, you can call `render json: object` from your controller. You can test this the same way you can test any other controller: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers

If you absolutely need it in ERB for whatever reason, you can call the `.to_json` method on the object between ERB tags: `<%= object.to_json %>`.

The `.to_json` method will always return valid JSON.

Comment: Should have told you this doesn't go through Rails. Just plain ERB and Ruby.

Comment: You should still be able to use the `json` gem to represent the object as json.